How to extract `raw_os_error` from any `reqwest::Error`?
Is it even possible?
Error #1:
reqwest::Error {
    kind: Request,
    url: "...",
    source: hyper_util::client::legacy::Error(
        Connect,
        ConnectError(
            "dns error",
            Os {
                code: 11001,
                kind: Uncategorized,
                message: "...",
            },
        ),
    ),
}

Code that extracts the i32 from the error #1:
if let Some(code) = reqwest_error
    .source()
    .and_then(|e| e.downcast_ref::<HyperUtilError>())
    .and_then(|e| e.source())
    .and_then(|e| e.source())
    .and_then(|e| e.downcast_ref::<IOError>())
    .and_then(|e| e.raw_os_error())
{
    return Some(code);
}


If I understand right the error #2:
reqwest::Error {
    kind: Request,
    url: "...",
    source: hyper_util::client::legacy::Error(
        Connect,
        Os {
            code: -2146893048,
            kind: Uncategorized,
            message: "...",
        },
    ),
}

Can be parsed with this code:
if let Some(code) = reqwest_error
    .source()
    .and_then(|e| e.downcast_ref::<HyperUtilError>())
    .and_then(|e| e.source())
    .and_then(|e| e.downcast_ref::<IOError>())
    .and_then(|e| e.raw_os_error())
{
    return Some(code);
}

But the downcast of error #2 to the IOError fails. Even though when I log error #1 and #2 right before casting them to IOError they look identical: Os {...}.
What am I doing wrong? My guess is that the most nested elements of this errors are just different. And in case of error #2 it can't be downcasted to IOError. But how do I find out the correct type then?
Maybe there's a better way/best practice to extract the nested errors like these.
P.S. reqwest_error is reqwest::Error, HyperUtilError is hyper_util::client::legacy::Error, IOError is std::io::Error.

If you print HyperUtilError::source(), what does it print?

@ChayimFriedman HyperUtilError::source(&e) after casting reqwest_error.source() to HyperUtilError?
For error #1:
ConnectError("dns error", Os {code: 11001, kind: Uncategorized, message: "..."})
For error #2:
Os {code: -2146893048, kind: Uncategorized, message: "..."}

And if you print the downcast::<IOError>()?

@ChayimFriedman well, if we'll take only the order of actions from my previous comment into account - nothing will be printed for both errors. In case of error #1 we need to call source() method one more time and only then downcast the result to IOError. In case of error #2 it's just nothing and that's it. Ultimately the problem is that Os {code: 11001, kind: Uncategorized, message: "..."} can be downcasted to IOError while Os {code: -2146893048, kind: Uncategorized, message: "..."}- can't be.

I'm afraid this is too generic to be answered. If you cannot provide additional details (e.g. a Minimal Reproducible Example), I will vote for this to be closed.

@ChayimFriedman since I don't know the type of the most nested error and that's what the problem is - i can't provide a minimal reproducible example (create the error object manually)...eh...you can close the question. Will I be able to edit the closed question if I find the solution?

If you cannot post your current code that creates the error, try patching reqwest to always return an error of this kind. And if the question is closed you will be able to edit it but not post an answer, which is the thing you are supposed to do if you find a solution.
